# How to use only filterd measures in a visuel in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table [Exhibitor] with two columns "Exhibitor ID" and "Booth Space m²".
[image]
I have two Slicer "Area Cut of - A" and "Area Cut of - B" where I can set the cat of for a classification. They are "what if parameter" `'z_Booth Space CutOff - A'` and `'z_Booth Space CutOff - B'` that are awailable in the following two measures:

```
Booth Space A CutOff = min('z_Booth Space CutOff - A'[Booth Space CutOff - A])
Booth Space B CutOff = min('z_Booth Space CutOff - B'[Booth Space CutOff - B])
```

What I need are two more measures `Measure Clas A` and `Measure Clas B` (it can not be a calculated columns) that I can use in a visual to sum up how many exhibitors are in the Classification A  or in Classification B.

The final table **visual** should look like this:
[image]

Since there are no other values of the [Exhibitor] table used in this visual I need the measures to do the calculation and grouping. How should I create the measures and how should I set up the visuals configuration?

Can anyone help? Please let me know.

Comment: I would recommend you share a better diagram of the model, sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: More Details are awailable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "What if parameter" as a filter in measures. Please, see the example below.

```
CountValues = COUNTROWS('Table')

CountWithCutoff =
CALCULATE ( [CountValues], FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[num] >= [LowerCutoff] ) )
```

[image]